# How does Twitter put labels inside textboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the [twitter](http://twitter.com/) login page, the label for input fields arrive inside input fields that uses a common trick with javascript/jquery. However, I went through a twitter source to figure out how they are doing that. I found onChange: it adds a class 'hasome' to a parent div and has a default text as a span, which never gets a property like `display:none;`.

I have tried to go through their HTML/CSS/JS but could not find their methods. Can someone please tell how [twitter](http://twitter.com/) is doing that?

**Edit**
Twitter code:

```
<div class="placeholding-input username hasome">
    <input type="text" class="text-input email-input" name="session[username_or_email]" title="Username or email" autocomplete="on" tabindex="1">
    <span class="placeholder">Username or email</span>
</div>
```

Added twitter HTML in question. When we add some code, it only add one class 'hasome' in parent div. in firebug, I could not see any property assigned to class 'hassome'. My question is where is there code which is doing that or CSS if it is achieved by CSS.

Comment: To the person who is putting downvote may please justify their action?

Comment: Not downvoter, but I can see a reason: every browser allows you to select an element and look at all styles set on the element - should not be too hard to pick one that are of interest... And that come back for explanation if needed.

Comment: Yes correct. I know that and used firebug/devtools to figure out they are adding 'hasclass'. After that they could not help anymore to go through very long script catching some events. I put the question expecting someone else had already gone through it. I could produce same effect but I stuck at twitter as earlier this week I could not find the way they are using. On weekend, I just took that as one of the weekend assignments. I'm also going through their JS and update the question if I found their way (event capture code).

Comment: Note sure I follow where you have problem with finding styles on element - all styles are shown along with CSS file their are coming from directly in F12 window... (I like IE one as it keeps selected element... but FF one allows to see styles too the same way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `hasome` class is applied to the parent div, it's used in a selector that's setting CSS values on the *child* span. So in Firebug (or Chrome or IE's developer tools), you'll need to keep an eye on that child span, not the div, to see what's going on.

You should end up seeing the following rules applied, from the CSS file t1_core_logged_out.bundle.css:

```
.has-content .placeholder, .hasome .placeholder
{
    font-size:0!important;
    z-index:-1;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    opacity:0;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

The part of the rule that ends up taking effect is the ".hasome .placeholder" part: when an element with style .placeholder has an ancestor with class .hasome, then various techniques are used to hide that child element. It's basically using a class on a parent to control styles of a child or descendant, which is a fairly common CSS technique.

Comment: Oh correct. I missed that change in child element. My bad. I should go to sleep I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is not what they are doing, you can accomplish the same result by using the HTML5 attribute [placeholder](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute)

Keep in mind that this is [supported by most major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder) with the regular exception of IE. So if this is not a concern for you, you can definitely use this.

Comment: Although that is a good way to accomplish a similar result, it is not what they are doing, in this case.

Comment: @iioiooioo You beat me to that, I was just checking their source code and realized that they are using it. Edited the answer

Comment: It's funny that they're not, given the almost exact behavior and not adding any fancy effects, coupled with the fact that they're not using real labels. It's hard to imagine what advantage this might give, other then the slight fade on focus...

Comment: the advantage is the placeholder attribute is not widely supported, and they would probably rather have just one solution for the label presentation that works for all.

Comment: I was shocked when I saw their source, but I am pretty sure they have a pretty good reason!

Comment: Oddly enough, they do use @placeholder in some other pages, just not here.

Answer (score 2):

It's just displaying an absolutely positioned span over the field, then hiding it as soon as anything is entered (and re-displaying it when the field becomes blank again). The immediate hiding is why it doesn't matter that the span obscures the field. Oddly, it doesn't look like they actually used labels, although I don't see a good reason not to have.

Comment: I added twitter HTML in question. When we add some code, it only add one class 'hasome' in parent div. in firebug, I could not see any property assigned to class 'hassome'. My question is where is there code which is doing that or CSS if it is achieved by CSS.

Comment: It's most likely caused by one or more bits of all of that obfuscated javascript adding handlers for key up and focus and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

It's CSS.
http://a0.twimg.com/a/1347042098/t1/css/t1_core_logged_out.bundle.css has the following rule:

`.hasome .placeholder{font-size:0!important;z-index:-1;-moz-opacity:0;opacity:0;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";filter:alpha(opacity=0);}`

Notice that for any `.placeholder` in a `.hasome`, its `opacity` is set to `0`. Therefore, it doesn't show.

Not the way I would have done it, but that's how they're doing it at least.